# Does spring initialize beans in parallel?

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I have a lot of **independent** spring beans in my project (classes annotated with `@Component` -- **NOT lazily initialized**). I wanted to know weather the beans will be initialized serially or parallely?
I am asking this because the beans modify a common data structure on initialization and I wanted to know weather the data structure should be made thread-safe.

Spring version used:- **4.2**

I was reading open issues on spring jira website:-

According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/14520 (formerly SPR-9887) it seems to be parallely initialized

But according to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13410 (formerly SPR-8767) it seems to be serially initialized.

Comment: Read again. The request is to do it parallel currently it is serial. So no nothing is done in parallel, none-the-less making things thread safe is always a good thing. Also the issue is regarding component-scanning which is something different them initializing/creating beans. Although they are related.

Answer (score 4):

Spring initialises beans in serial. There is nothing that says that they are initialised in parallel. In fact, the ticket that you cite (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9887) is a closed ticket because it's a duplicate of https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8767. This ticket is unresolved and targetted for the release of spring 5.0 in the future, so nothing says that beans are initialised in parallel!

Comment: Starting in 4.3 Spring processes JPA/Hibernate in the background during startup, so at least there's some parallelization now.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13732

Comment: Finally! It's possible to initialize beans in parallel starting from 6.2.0-M1: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13410#issuecomment-1967596598